# How to generate SQL update statements with IDE?

Tags: sql, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, auto-generate

I have table in dev environment something like this

```
EMP_ID     NAME     DEPT
  1         A        AA
  2         B        BB
  3         C        CC
```

and I have same table in test environment but with null values in DEPT column. Is there anyway to generate update statements based on EMP_ID so that I can copy DEPT values from dev to test?
For example IDE should generate : `update EMPLOYEE set dept='AA' where EMP_ID=1`.
I use Oracle Sqldeveloper and PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: How big are these tables?

Comment: I have 100+ records now.

Comment: If you could create a dbLink between your DBs, plain SQL should be enough

Comment: If you want an exact copy of the production table in test, and the rows number is rather small, you can also consider copy-paste :)
@GurV solution is much more elegant and versatile though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute the below query to generate your update statements and copy the result which you can execute in your other environment.

```
select 
    'update employee set dept = ''' || dept || ''' where emp_id = ' || emp_id || ';'
from employee;
```